# openPopup() in leaflet map using custom link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, leaflet, markerclusterer

I am trying to trigger the marker popup window in leaflet map but having no luck. I am using cluster map which works fine and open the popup window when user clicks on a marker. I need to extend this e.g. passing a parameter through url and open the specific marker based on the url parameter value on page load. I am using the following code for map clustering.

```
        var latlng = L.latLng(-30.81881, 116.16596);
    var map = L.map('lmap', { center: latlng, zoom: 6 });
    var lcontrol = new L.control.layers();
    var eb = new L.control.layers();


    //clear map first
    clearMap();
    //resize the map
    map.invalidateSize(true);
    //load the map once all layers cleared
    loadMap();
    //reset the map size on dom ready
    map.invalidateSize(true);
function loadMap() {

        var markers_array = [];

        var roadMutant = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({
            type: 'roadmap' // valid values are 'roadmap', 'satellite', 'terrain' and 'hybrid'
        }).addTo(map);


        //add the control on the map

       lcontrol= L.control.layers({
            Roadmap: roadMutant

        }, {}, {
            collapsed: false
        }).addTo(map);

    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({chunkedLoading: true, spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true, maxClusterRadius: 80, showCoverageOnHover: true });

    //clear markers and remove all layers
    markers.clearLayers();


    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: appUrl + "/Home/map", 
        data: {'atype': st},
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                var img = (item.IconUrl).replace("~", "");
                var Icon = L.icon({ iconUrl: img, iconSize: [42, 42] });

                var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude), { icon: Icon }, { title: item.Name });
                var content = "<div class='infoDiv'><h3><img src='" + appUrl + img + "' width='24' />" + item.Name + "</h3><p>" + item.Title + "</p><a href='#' data-value='" + item.AlertId + "' class='btn btn-success btn-sm alertInfo' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#alertDetails'>Details</a></div>";
                marker.bindPopup(content);
                markers.addLayer(marker);
                //add the marker to array
                markers_array.push(marker);

            });

        }

    })
   .done(function () {
       $(".loadingOverlay").hide();
       map.invalidateSize(true);
   });

    //add the markers to the map
   map.addLayer(markers);

}
```

I have tried to implement the following custom click event but no luck.

```
function markerFunction(id) {
       alert(markers_array.length);

       for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i) {
           var mid = markers_array[i]["_leaflet_id"];

           if (mid == id) {
                alert("opening " + id);
               map.markers(id).openPopup();

               }
           }
          }
    //trigger on link click
   $("a").click(function () {
       var id = $(this).attr("id");
       alert(id);
       markerFunction(id);

   });
```

Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Zoom to and Spiderfy MarkerClusterGroup, open popup of target marker](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181372/zoom-to-and-spiderfy-markerclustergroup-open-popup-of-target-marker/181395#181395) on GIS SE (but omit the spiderfy part)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried this but it does not work. `code` var target = markers.getLayer(markers_array[id])
           markers.zoomToShowLayer(target, function () {
               target.openPopup();
           })

Comment: Please make sure you debug your code as much as possible first. Edit your question rather than posting code in comment. If possible, reproduce your issue on an online editing tool, using [SO built-in code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), Plunker, JSFiddle, JSBin, etc. All that will help you get faster support, if not enabling you to find a solution by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`loadMap()` acquires its data asynchronously. Anything that works with that data (or anything derived from that data) must do so in a way that takes account of the asynchronism, typically in a chained `.then()`.

As it stands, markers are created asynchronously but the click handler is independently defined and attached. Delivering `markers_array` (and `markers`?) via a promise returned from `loadMap()` will allow the necessary marker data to be fully populated at the point of attachment and brought into scope of the click handler.

I would write something like this :

```
var latlng = L.latLng(-30.81881, 116.16596);
var map = L.map('lmap', { center: latlng, zoom: 6 });
var lcontrol = new L.control.layers(); // necessary?
var eb = new L.control.layers(); // necessary?

clearMap(); // why, it's only just been created?
map.invalidateSize(true);
loadMap(map).then(function(obj) {
    $(".loadingOverlay").hide();
    map.invalidateSize(true); // again?

    $("a").click(function(e) { // jQuery selector probably needs to be more specific
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        for(var i=0; i<obj.markers_array.length; ++i) {
            if(obj.markers_array[i]._leaflet_id == id) {
                map.markers(id).openPopup(); // if `map.markers` is correct, maybe you don't need obj.markers?
                break; // break out of `for` loop on success.
            }
        }
    });
    return obj;
});

function loadMap(map) {
    var roadMutant = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({ type: 'roadmap' }).addTo(map);
    var lcontrol = L.control.layers({Roadmap: roadMutant}, {}, {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);

    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: appUrl + '/Home/map', 
        data: {'atype': st},
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }).then(function (data) {
        var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({chunkedLoading: true, spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true, maxClusterRadius: 80, showCoverageOnHover: true });
        markers.clearLayers();
        var markers_array = $.map(data, function(item) {
            var img = (item.IconUrl).replace("~", "");
            var Icon = L.icon({ iconUrl: img, iconSize: [42, 42] });
            var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude), { icon: Icon }, { title: item.Name });
            var content = "<div class='infoDiv'><h3><img src='" + appUrl + img + "' width='24' />" + item.Name + "</h3><p>" + item.Title + "</p><a href='#' data-value='" + item.AlertId + "' class='btn btn-success btn-sm alertInfo' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#alertDetails'>Details</a></div>";
            marker.bindPopup(content);
            markers.addLayer(marker);
            return marker;
        });
        map.addLayer(markers); //add the markers to the map
        // If both 'markers_array' and 'markers' are needed later, then bundle them into an object.
        // If not, then simply return one or other of those variables.
        return {
            'markers_array': markers_array,
            'markers': markers
        };
    });
}
```

The detail will need checking, but the overall pattern should be correct.

Comment: Hi Roamer, thanks heaps for your help. I am getting `TypeError: t.markers is not a function` in debug window when I try `obj.markers(id).openPopup();` am I missing something.

Comment: That's the line I'm uncertain of. Try `obj.markers_array[i].openPopup();`

Comment: Thanks again, I have tried that still same error. Anyway I have come up with alternate solution.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, you shouldn't need both `markers` and `markers_array` because the array can be obtained with `markers.getAllChildMarkers()` (if you need it). Therefore, simply `return markers` from loadMap's inner function and adjust `loadMap(map).then(...)` accordingly (to expect `markers` not `obj`). After that, it may be as simple as `markers.getLayer(id).openPopup()` - it's hard to tell - the documentation is a little hazy.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what your alternate solution is.

Answer (score 0):

After spending too much time on this, I have come up with a different approach. Pass a parameter through URL as hash (#) value. Grab the value using jQuery selector and fetch data for that record then open the popup on the map. Here is my second code block -

```js
$(function () {
           var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);// "90aab585-1641-43e9-9979-1b53d6118faa";
           
           if (!hash) return false;
          
           //show loading
           $(".loadingOverlay").show();


           $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: appUrl + "/Home/GetAlert/"+hash, 
               dataType: 'json',
               contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
               success: function (data) {
                   if (!data.status)
                   {
                       $('#msg').html(data.message).attr("class","alert alert-warning");
                       $(".loadingOverlay").hide();
                       return false;
                   }
                   $.each(data.message, function (i, item) {
                      
                       var popupLoc = new L.LatLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude);
                       var popupContent = "<div class='infoDiv'><h3><img src='" + appUrl + img + "' width='24' />" + item.Name + "</h3><p>" + item.Title + "</p><a href='#' data-value='" + item.AlertId + "' class='btn btn-success btn-sm alertInfo' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#alertDetails'>Details</a></div>";

                       //initialize the popup;
                     var popup = new L.Popup();
                       //set latlng
                       popup.setLatLng(popupLoc);
                       //set content
                       popup.setContent(popupContent);
                       map.setView(new L.LatLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude), 8);
                      //display popup
                       map.addLayer(popup);
                      
                   });

               }

           })
       .done(function () {
           $(".loadingOverlay").hide();        
           map.invalidateSize(true);
       });
          
       });
```